# Turning a paragraph of phrases into a list

Tags: php

I'd like to use something like `preg_replace` or `ereg replace`, to turn a paragraph of phrases such as the one below:

```
This is one This is two This is three This is four
```

To a list, such as the one below:

This is one

This is two

This is three

This is four

notice that I'm only targeting the spaces before the upper case letters.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any luck with either of the provided answers or questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = "This is one This is two This is three This is four";
$arr = explode (" " , $word);
$lines = array_chunk($arr,3);
foreach($lines as $line) 
echo implode (" ", $line)."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match_all`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php, for this.

```
preg_match_all('~([A-Z][^A-Z]+)~', 'This is one This is two This is three This is four', $sentances);
print_r($sentances[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is one 
    [1] => This is two 
    [2] => This is three 
    [3] => This is four
)
```

Demo (also explanation of regex): https://regex101.com/r/zW4iW0/1
PHP Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2be9da124130c2259d10336837ff9c8405ce495a

Also note that most (all?) `e` reg PHP functions(and the modifier) are deprecated.

> Warning
>   This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php